Using JSON mode with OpenAI package for R
I'm using Openai package in for the R language. I'm looking for a way to switch to JSON mode with the completion api.
At the moment I'm using the create_chat_completion function such as:
create_chat_completion( model = model_type,
                        messages = user_conversation,
                        temperature = model_temperature,
                        max_tokens = model_max_tokens,
                        top_p = 1,
                        frequency_penalty = 0,
                        presence_penalty  = 0 )

Documentation do not provide any hint on that and isn't clear to me if there is something similar to the python such as response_format={ "type": "json_object" } or if I've to build this with a raw httR calls with the rights tool specification:
tools = [
    {
        "type": "function",
        "function": {
            "name": "ask_database",
            "description": "Use this function to answer user questions about music. Input should be a fully formed SQL query.",
            "parameters": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "query": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": f"""
                                SQL query extracting info to answer the user's question.
                                SQL should be written using this database schema:
                                {database_schema_string}
                                The query should be returned in plain text, not in JSON.
                                """,
                    }
                },
                "required": ["query"],
            },
        }
    }
]


Thanks

In R both ( and { are taken as signals to the interpreter to evaluate the contained symbols. So I doubt they could get passed intact to Python.

I know R sintax, I simply ask if there are any way to include the tool option via OpenAI package.

My point was that unless you take steps to prevent the R interpreter from encountering it in an unquoted form that they will be seen as R language objects.
